# Hippo CMS - Allowing all registered members adding articles?

Tags: java, content-management-system, hippocms

Hi
I wanted to create a web portal and allow every registered user to add an article. So from this point of view each portal member would become an author (by default). 
I was also thinking about letting these members to create articles with 2-3 predefined templates (let's say 2-3 edit sections and several custom components). 
Is it possible to do it? 
Where to start?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want to create the document using the website/portal or using the CMS.

Hippo CMS has all the functionality you are looking for - multiple authors, pre-defined document templates etc.

But if you want to create the document using the webiste/portal then you need to take a different approach.

The document creation in Hippo CMS is driven by Workflow. Using Hippo Site Toolkit you can create a document but that means creating a document using a pre-defined workflow user. So the document created in CMS will not have the author as the portal user that created the document.

You can check out the Go Green demo project that will give some hints on how to create a document from within the website. Checkout the page http://www.demo.onehippo.com/products, the "Suggest a Product" form is creating a "Product" document in CMS automatically.

The source code for the demo is at : http://svn.onehippo.org/repos/hippo/hippo-demos/hippo-go-green/trunk/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the svn repo, I've been looking everywhere for it!